# Cell border causes calendar to get bigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have a custom asp.net calendar. When a date is selected, it runs this style:

```
.calendar-cell
{
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: rgb(239,239,239); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(239,239,239,1) 0%, rgba(235,235,235,1) 50%, rgba(229,229,229,1) 51%, rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(239,239,239,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(235,235,235,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(229,229,229,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(254,254,254,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(239,239,239,1) 0%,rgba(235,235,235,1) 50%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(239,239,239,1) 0%,rgba(235,235,235,1) 50%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(239,239,239,1) 0%,rgba(235,235,235,1) 50%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */ /* W3C */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: inherit;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(239,239,239,1) 0%,rgba(235,235,235,1) 50%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 51%,rgba(254,254,254,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#efefef', endColorstr='#fefefe',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
    border-collapse:collapse !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    color: #019fde !important;
}
```

Which adds a border.

This causes the entire calendar to get bigger.

I have tried the border spacing and collapse properties with no luck.

Is there a way to just make the calendar not grow when borders are added to selected dates?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's how borders work.  If your border is 1px wide, then it takes up 1px of space.

You could use the `outline` property instead.  It is virtually identical to border, but without the undesirable additional width/height that comes with it.  You can see in the demo below that the collection of elements containing the outlined element is 20px narrower than the one containing the bordered element.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/wyktr

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="solid"></div>
  <div class="bordered"></div>
  <div class="solid"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="solid"></div>
  <div class="outlined"></div>
  <div class="solid"></div>
</div>

div.container {
  display: table;
  margin: 1em;
}

div.container div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.bordered {
  border: 10px solid orange;
}

.outlined {
  outline: 10px solid red;
}

.solid {
  background: #CCC;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#search=outline

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use **outline** which will not increase size or you can use **box-sizing** which takes borders into the the content space.

example here 
http://jsfiddle.net/Y5VmT/

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: grey;
}

.sizing {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


<div>
    pppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppp
    pppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppp
    pppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppp
</div>


<div class="sizing">
    pppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppp
    pppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppp
    pppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppp pppppppppppppppppppppp
</div>
```